# Accessing storage after migrating from Ionic to React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ionic-framework, nsuserdefaults, capacitor

I published an app in Ionic 4, React and Capacitor Storage Plugin. I am working to rewrite the app using React Native. The app has active users and I want them to keep their progress as much as possible. According to the documentation of Ionic Storage Plugin: "On iOS this plugin will use UserDefaults and on Android SharedPreferences."

I've found a similar solution for React Native called 'rn-user-defaults'. However, the same key used to store user's data retrieves undefined. I use for both versions (Ionic and Native) the same Bundle Identifier, the same product name and I confirm that only in the Ionic version the storage is being retrieved.

If anyone knows what may be the problem, I would highly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone wondering, the rn-user-defaults works fine for ios, but you need to add "_cap_" as user defaults key as prefix. I also believe the bundle id should be the same. Still trying to manage to get this working on Android.

Comment: Did you manage to get it working on both? Could you post the right answer?